# Difference between two SQL Server queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I want to know the difference between two SQL Server queries?

**Tables:**

[image]

[image]

What I am want to do is that join the above tables and apply filters. One of such filter is based on another table.

[image]

**Query#1**

```sql
UPDATE STORE_ITEM
SET user_bit_5 = '1'
FROM STORE_ITEM
     INNER JOIN tag_demand ON STORE_ITEM.item_id = tag_demand.item_id
                          AND STORE_ITEM.store_nbr = tag_demand.store_nbr
WHERE tag_demand.print_dt = '2022-04-11'
  AND tag_demand.STORE_NBR IN (SELECT store_nbr FROM store WHERE division_id = 'XYZ')
  AND user_bit_5 = '0';
```

**Query#2**

```
UPDATE STORE_ITEM
SET user_bit_5 = '1'
FROM STORE_ITEM
     INNER JOIN tag_demand ON STORE_ITEM.item_id = tag_demand.item_id
                          AND STORE_ITEM.store_nbr = tag_demand.store_nbr
                          AND tag_demand.print_dt = '2022-04-11'
                          AND tag_demand.STORE_NBR IN (SELECT store_nbr FROM store WHERE division_id = 'XYZ')
WHERE user_bit_5 = '0';
```

First query has more conditions on the join while the second query has them on the where clause.

Comment: There are, effectively, no differences. Just, one has moved some of the clauses in the `WHERE` to the `ON` (and I would suggest that they do not belong there, as they have no relation to the `JOIN` criteria).

Comment: @Larnu - understood. should I go with Query#2 to reduce the overall execution time?

Comment: If you want to determine the execution time for each (which will probably be exactly the same, SQL query optimiser is pretty smart) just run them together in a batch and turn on visualisation of the execution plan

Comment: Like I mentioned, I would suggest that the first query is more "grammatically correct", however, from the database engine's point of view, the 2 statements would very likely to processed identically (with the 2 statements that were migrated to the `ON` from the `WHERE` likely being processed more like they are `WHERE` clauses).

Comment: `SET user_bit_5 = '1'` The name suggests the datatype is bit - which is a numeric datatype. If true, then why do you use string constants and rely on implicit conversion. Develop GOOD habits.

Comment: Also, you should be using *aliases* to aid readability and clarity. Especially important if your correlated query were to share column names in multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No differences in the particular queries you showed us. SQL Server's query planner will probably use similar, if not identical, operations to satisfy both.

Still, your second query pattern, when used with `LEFT JOIN`, and with SELECT **not UPDATE**, is quite common. With `LEFT JOIN` a query like your second one would always return at least one row from `STORE_ITEM`, even if it found no matching rows from `tag_demand`.

(If you use `LEFT JOIN` instead of ordinary `INNER JOIN` in your second query, you will update all rows in your `STORE_ITEM` table.)